# Why does OpenGL have global functions?

Tags: c++, opengl, paradigms

Why isn't openGL object-orientied? Everybody teaches Object Orientated Programming + Design Patterns, but OpenGL has many global functions. **Isn't this bad style?**

Comment: If you want a cleaner, object oriented OpenGL interface, consider using a middleware package like the open-source OpenSceneGraph.

Comment: @James, actually your comment greatly illustrates the reason -- I consider OSG ugly, and would never want to adapt that design... but thanks to OpenGL's low level-ness I can rollup my own :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The whole point of a low-level API is to make it as minimal and portable as possible. Giving it an object-oriented architecture would not allow this:

- Polymorphism adds unnecessary function call overhead.
- It forces you to use some relatively difficult calling convention, which reduces portability.
- You cannot wrap an object-oriented architecture to make it procedural, but you can do the reverse; so, it makes sense to make things as flexible as possible. It's trivial to write an object-oriented wrapper around OpenGL if you want.

Finally, you should really question what you've been taught about OOP. Despite what your college or university may tell you, OOP is not a panacea of program design. There are very good reasons why there is absolutely no object-orientation in the C++ STL (and most of Boost for that matter).

Object-orientation is useful in some cases, but you should learn when it is useful, and when it is not, and under no circumstances should you believe that anything that is not OOP is "bad style".

Answer (score 11):

OpenGL

- OpenGL should support all platforms -- there's nothing near to C in this regard - thanks to that almost every device can use the same API
- OpenGL should support all languages -- there's also nothing near to C in this regard - thanks to that, each language that supports calling C libraries (and almost all do) can use OpenGL
- OpenGL is an API, not a engine -- it intends to provide **low level** interface to the graphics harware, yet enough high level, to be an abstraction to different hardwares -- C is a lot more low level than C++, OOP is not low level
- OpenGL is a framework to build upon, not a complete solution -- there is no *one and true way* to write graphics code, and OpenGL isn't supposed to force us to anything - by being OOP it would force us to their "colution
- OpenGL is *not* tied to any specific programming paradigm -- hence we can wrap OpenGL into a functional, logical or OOP language -- or use it procedurally
- OpenGL is about efficiency -- and you can't get more efficient than by direct function calls. OOP is as efficient as it is suited for a particular task.

In general -- OpenGL is designed to allow us to have all the freedom, and don't make any choices for us. And by freedom I mean freedom to choose a platform, a language, a programming paradigm, a engine design, a methodology, and a level of efficiency vs. readability.

And for that I praise OpenGL, and for that I hate Direct X.

Amen.

***Sidenote:*** Everybody teaches Object Orientated programming because it's the easiest to grasp. It's not the one and only true paradigm. There's functional programming, logical programming, contract programming, and even a object oriented way to write in C. There's no one truth in computer science. As for Design Patterns, I could name more than a few that are used in OpenGL's architecture. Bad Style? I've seen beautiful C programs that had aaaaallll global functions...

Comment: I like your answer, it's a more fleshed out version of what I was trying to say. :) Also, I agree with GL versus DX. I used to swear by DX, but I finally tried OpenGL, and even though I think it could be cleaned up immensely, the amount of flexibility and control it offers is fantastic, not to mention the entire extensions system. I can actually take advantage of very specific features and fall back more and more until one works, and even use one vendor specific helper if I want, or my own generic implementation. You could never try to design such a system in DX.

Comment: @GMan, and besides of that, lets be honest -- there is no API besides OpenGL if one wants to look at something else than Windows and XBox...

Comment: Totally true. It's a shame more people don't tap into the power of OpenGL. Admittedly you have to know a little more to start using it, but that's ok.

Comment: I agree to this, just begun with OpenGL in C# with the OpenTK framework, and boy do I love it. I found XNA a pain, this is actually fun!

Answer (score 8):

In general, OpenGL **is** object oriented. It is just implemented in a language that doesn't directly support OOP. But the API is object-oriented: It consists of a number of different object types, and a set of operations defined on each. And the internals of each object type are hidden from the user. It fulfills all the requirements for OOP. It just so happens to be implemented in C, which doesn't have a convenient class or member method syntax.

Apart from this, there is absolutely nothing wrong with global functions. In C++, a common recommendation is to prefer them over member methods whenever possible. In functional programmming, global functions are the default.

Comment: Cool, anonymous downvotes. Nothing quite like knowing what people disagree with in your post.

Comment: OpenGL is not object-oriented at all. There are no classes in OpenGL, only raw data types. Since there are no classes, there are no objects and obviously no methods that can be called on objects. Again, everything is just raw data that changes the state of the OpenGL FSM.

There's no message passing (because there are no objects).
There's no inheritance (no classes).
There's no polymorphism (no classes).

The only thing that the OpenGL API shares with OOP is that it is an abstraction, but it abstracts the internals using procedures, not objects and class hierarchies.

Comment: +1: for object orientation. Poita_ have you ever written FBO's or VBO's?

Comment: @Poita: I think if you understood what it means to have "classes" or "objects", it would be clear you can program OOP in C. Consider Herb Sutter's "Interface Principle" if you don't get what I mean: Data + methods to operate on that data == Object. And guess what the interface provides.

Comment: @GMan, the day I saw a cleanly written OOP C program, I **almost** started to like C :P.

Comment: @GMan, I understand this, but I further think that you don't understand what OOP is. OOP is not simply programming with objects, that's just object programming. Object-oriented programming is specifically referring to the things I mentioned above (e.g. polymorphism, inheritance, class hierarchies, message passing etc.)

If an object is just data and manipulation of data then does that mean all C programming is OOP? I don't think so.

Finally, at no point did I say that you can't program in the OOP style in C.

Comment: @Poita: Last point is fair, you didn't. But looks like we have different definitions of OOP. My version merely requires what's called objects (a collection of data) and the ability to manipulate that data. Boost doesn't use inheritance or message passing too often, does that means most of Boost isn't OO? I think your definition is too strict.

Comment: Most of Boost isn't OO. Perhaps we'll just have to agree to disagree on what OOP is, but I would like to hear your opinion on the question I asked in my last comment, namely: If an object is just data that can be manipulated through procedures then does that mean that all C programming is OOP in your definition? If so, then I think your definition of OOP is too broad, and if not, then what else does a program need beyond data and data manipulation to be OOP?

Comment: I'd just like to add something else as well: In your definition of OOP, is the STL OO? I know for a fact that Alexander Stepanov (the designer and main implementer of the STL) specifically created it NOT to be OOP because he thinks OOP is a farce.

Comment: @Poita_: The point is that you manipulate the data through a related set of procedures - not that any arbitrary procedure manipulates the data directly as it is often common in plain C. But then again there are some different interpretations of OOP out there.

Comment: @Poita_ So prototype-based languages such as Javascript or for that matter, Smalltalk, aren't object-oriented either? Someone needs to read up on the *original* meaning of OOP, I think. A `class` keyword is hardly essential. The thing about OpenGL is that it is *not* just manipulation of data. Every object is thoroughly encapsulated, their internals invisible as all the user sees is a handle, most functions are polymorphic in that they work on a range of different OGL objects.

Comment: And each object has a clearly defined set of functions that can access its internal representation, just like OOP member methods. How is this not OOP?

The STL too has OOP aspects. What Stepanov objected to wasn't the common-sense parts of OOP of abstraction and data hiding, but precisely the things that OGL *doesn't* have - the formalia of a "class" keyword, the loss of type safety or the inability to express generic code.

Comment: Not, not really OOP, to be OOP it needs the encapsulation at least, there is no encapsulation, you are not passing messages thru an object, operations and data are entirely separated, that simply isn't OOP. You can mentally model it as OOP, but it isn't OOP.

Comment: @IonTodirel no encapsulation? I you have a texture, say, all that is actually exposed to you is a handle (of type `GLuint`), and you can **only** access its internal state (the actual pixel data, for example) through the OpenGL API functions. Its internals are hidden and inaccessible. How is that *not* encapsulated? :) You can tell me that OpenGL does not feature encapsulation, or that operations and data are separated, when you figure out a way to modify a texture without going through the OpenGL API.

Comment: encapsulation isn't just about restricting everything, it's also about having the ability of exposing *something*, do any of the opengl "objects" provide that? are the operations on GLuint passed thru a GLuint? again, they aren't, GLuint is an opaque pointer (if what you say about having innaccesible internal state is correct) then, not an object

Comment: @IonTodirel: Of course they do. Continuing with the texture example, OpenGL provides functionality for binding it, for retrieving the pixel data, for specifying the pixel data. Please, show me in the book of rules where OOP implies "operations must be "passed through" the object (whatever that means). In Java, all that happens for a method is that it is called with an extra pointer, named "this". It does not "go through" the object, the language just provides syntax to make it look like that.

Comment: @IonTodirel heck, you know what a `String` is in Java? That's right, an opaque pointer. Sure, there's some data on the heap somewhere, but `String s` declares a completely opaque pointer and nothing else. Likewise with OpenGL textures, a `GLuint` is an opaque pointer. Useless in itself, but which can be used to access the backing object. Just like a string reference can be used to access the backing string.

Comment: passing messages (in the context of an object) is very central to OOP, you cannot have OOP without that, plain and simple, if you take the operations out of the object, then at that point it stops being OOP, it doesn't matter what you can emulate, OOP is about objects and maintainability, storing globale state to achieve the same doesn't make it more or less OOP; I don't know what a String is in Java, but in .NET a System.String is an object which encapsulates different sort of operations and state, it's not an opaque pointer

Comment: @IonTodirel C# doesn't have message-passing. You can call methods on an object, but you cannot send messages to one. So if we go by the strict definition, then C# isn't an OOP language either. Now, what exactly do you mean by "taking operations out of the object"? `System.String` doesn't *contain* any operations either. Any member function on `System.String` is actually just a free function which takes a hidden `this` reference as an extra parameter. The actual instructions making up the member functions are not located inside a `String` object.

Comment: So I guess you are saying that the *syntax* `foo.bar()` is what makes it OOP? That if we rewrite it as `bar(foo)`, it is no longer OOP, even if the semantics are *exactly* the same?

Comment: hey jalf, by message passing I mean "calling methods on an object", IIRC message passing is used pretty frequently in OOP terminology, it should not be broaden to other techniques for inter thread or inter process communication; but System.String do contains operations, when you query the length of a string "str", you use the "str.Length" notation, and not "get_Length(str)", that is OOP, how does it look under cover is unimportant, and you cannot reason that emulating the undercover implementation is OOP

Comment: if you can give me an example of an OOP language where messages to the object are not passed thru the object, I'd love to dispute it further, and be happy to chat with you more, I hope you are on facebook or gtalk

Comment: "So I guess you are saying that the syntax foo.bar() is what makes it OOP? That if we rewrite it as bar(foo), it is no longer OOP, even if the semantics are exactly the same?", that is exactly what I'm saying

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL was created for and in C, and none of that stuff existed then. Even now, they still want to keep a C interface, because C is still a widely used language.

Should they maintain both C interfaces and C++ wrappers, ditch C and just use C++, or keep a C interface? I'd argue the latter is the best solution: easy on them, not too hard for us.

That said, the OpenGL interface is admittedly gross. Lot's of stuff was "suppose" to be deprecated, but alas that got moved to a later date.

Comment: What do you consider gross? Also, I don't see a single really good reason in your post. Even if OpenGL would be designed today, it'd still be C.

Comment: @Kornel: Hence the keep the C interface. It's easy for everyone to use. Maybe I should have been more explicit: What I mean by that is almost every language can interface with a C library. As for the grossness, if you compare what OpenGL 3.0 was suppose to do to what it is, there's tons of useless and deprecated functions just hanging around. To me that makes it gross. If I wish to perform a task, a clean interface gives me one good flexible way to do that; not a bunch of different ways, where only one is considered the right way.

Comment: @GMan, that unfortunately can't be avoided -- there's tons of software written using deprecated functions. Personally I've cleaned my local OpenGL headers from all the deprecated functions -- it helps :)

Comment: @Kornel: I've never actually though of doing that, I tend to steer clear from modifying 3rd party headers. That said, I wrap up OpenGL so I no longer really have to touch it. :) Making wrappers is fun.

Comment: @GMan, I'm also currently working on a templated boost-like wrapper for GL... it's fun and furious at the same time D:

Comment: @Kornel: Ha, nice. I somewhat did that last year, but time constraints (school assignment, after all) forced me to cut back on the generality of it. How are the templates being used?

Comment: @GMan - for example the vertex is templated so that there's single code for any type of vertex encoding (3v3n3c, 2v2t, etc), the type of mesh is templated via the vertex definitions, and the code to handle them is determinated at runtime. And some more tricks :>

Comment: @Kornel: That sounds kind of like what I did. :3 fun times.

Comment: Another gross thing is the lack of compile-time type safety. When every data type is basically just represented by a typedef for an int, you have to keep track of which handles represent which types of objects yourself. That's a bit sloppy, and could easily have been avoided, even in a handle-based C API. Win32 manages it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are a few reasons.

- You should think of an OpenGL context as a state machine. There is only one of them active at any time. There is no difference between putting a little Opengl.whatever in front of everything.
- Speed, OpenGL was designed to be a minimal API
- If it was object oriented, what language would you write it in? C++? Then everybody would ahve to write complex bindings. C is WAY easier to wrap.

Comment: amen. c is easy to understand, easy to write. OO definitely shouldn't be the default.

Comment: and that's coming from a C++ fanatic ;)

Comment: Doesn't the fact that there can only be one context active at any time make it difficult/impossible to have two threads doing OpenGL calls simultaneously, since they would step on each other's context?  That seems like it could be a problem given the prevalence of multicore CPUs these days...

Comment: Well, yes. Only one thread can access a context at the same time and only one context can be active any any given time in a program. What's the point you're trying to make, and how does it relate to the asked question?

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz: Of course they could write bindings. Those would most likely involve wrapping the c++ api into extern c procedures (aka the kind of api we have now), but it would be possible

Comment: I wish OpenGL was more like OpenCV, OpenCV is a piece of beauty, it's using minimal OO features, and minimalist interfaces